Suspension and hibernation on Ubuntu 24.04 - Dell Precision 5490
I have a new Dell Precision 5490 Laptop that comes with Ubuntu 22.04, and I have installed the stock Ubuntu 24.04, but I have now problems I didn't "tested" with the shipped OS (I was too quick to move on Ubuntu 24.04), namely suspension and hibernation.
The laptop is quite powerful, as it comes with Intel Core Ultra 7 165H, 64 Gb of RAM and NVIDIA RTX2000 GPU.
Suspension "works" but eats 10% of the battery in 1 h !!! So, pretty useless.
Hibernation doesn't, even if I followed all the steps in this long tutorial:

I have updated the bios to the latest version and disables Secure Boot
as I had a swap file of "only" 8 GB vs a RAM of 32 GB I created a swap partition of 70GB and added to fstab (it works) - /dev/nvme0n1p5 / UUID e4e24763-b174-4057-9ebe-2aa34a423583
I have added the option resume=UUID=e4e24763-b174-4057-9ebe-2aa34a423583 to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter in /etc/default/grub and I have run update-grub
I have created a file /etc/tmpfiles.d/hibernation_resume.conf with content :

#    Path                   Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
w    /sys/power/resume       -    -    -    -   259:5

(I have also tried adding w /sys/power/image_size - - - - 8036093952 but I don't know what does it means... of course I would like to be hibernated only the actual RAM in use, not all the 64GB that I need only in particular circumstances)

I have created a file /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume with content resume=UUID=e4e24763-b174-4057-9ebe-2aa34a423583 and run sudo update-initramfs -c -k all

Still, running systemctl hibernate "seems" to work, but then the pc freeze on restart and need a physical power reset.
Any idea what else could I try ?
EDIT
I reverted to Dell Ubuntu 22.04 where ibernation still not works, but I have discovered that if I hibernate from a tty terminal (e.g. CTR+ALT+F4) then, when I have the black screen comig back from hibernation, I can again press CTR+ALT+F4 and "see" the old session, but there is nothing else I can do, can't type and have to manually bruteforece take down the system.
So the issue is not on bios or getting the wrong partition, but has to do with login and taking on X on post hibernation.

Can you add the output of 'swapon -show' an append to your question. Useful links https://www.bentasker.co.uk/posts/documentation/linux/using-multiple-swap-partitions-in-a-specific-order-on-linux.html https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613265/what-is-swap-priority-and-why-does-it-matter

@david: it shows the partition, that is working as expected: Filename: /dev/nvme0n1p5 Type: partition Size: 78124028 Used: 0 Priority: -2

I asked to see the output as I wanted to see how many swap spaces you have active and their respective priorities. Hibernation will use the one with the highest priority. I woud recommend comenting swapfile from the fstab. The tutorial states for the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT you should append with your swap partition name 'resume=/dev/nvme0n1p5'. All the  'resume=UUID=the-system-partition’s-uuid resume_offset=physical-offset-id' is for a swap file only.  As is the creation of the /etc/tmpfiles.d/hibernation_resume.conf file.

Thanks @david . Indeed in the fstab I have always a single swap file/partition in my different attempts. I have tried also creating a swapfile and using that, but nothing. I have a feeling my problem arise after that step, perhaps linked to the NVIDIA card? Or perhaps on an error I have just before the laptop go in hibernation, something related to hid_core_resume and i2c_hid_acpi failed to thaw async error... Sometimes (random??) the system riemerge from hibernation showing the time on the center, but it remain frozen (and SSH on it doesn't work)
